I'm just going to run it down this glass rod. | Why "...down...." instead of "....through"...?
A scientist is showing how he did an experiment, where he is pouring a liquid into a glass tube. While he is doing it, he said:
I'm just going to run it down this glass rod. BBC - Searching for the philisopher's stone (see:2:10 - 2 :12)
"...run it down..." caught my attention. I thought "run something down" must be a phrasal verb, and I looked it up, however the meanings don't sit well.
Then I thought maybe it is not a phrasal verb but "to run" is used on its own as a verb, so "run the liquid" makes sense, however then I wonder why "...down the glass rod" instead of  "..... through the glass rod".
Isn't "through" used for such stuctures as "through the tunnel, through the window, through the door, etc"?

The choice of down, through, down through and others often depends on physical context. Down the rod is perfectly normal in here; it indicates that the liquid ran downwards along the rod.
Note that a rod is normally solid, while a tube has a hollow core. It is common when pouring liquids to use a glass rod to guide the liquid and avoid splashing. The liquid in this case follows the glass because of capillary attraction.

... run it down the glass rod is right.  He was using the surface of the glass rod, not the internal of a tube, to convey down the liquid.
... run it through the glass tube would be appropriate to describe the latter case.

By saying "surface of the glass rod", how do you mean? Isn't it a tube-like structure, where is the surface of it?

The video shows the liquid being poured straight onto the surface of the rod.

@Yunus We used to do this in school chemistry lessons, 60 years ago, and I have heard of people with lab experience decanting wine from bottles to carafes that way.
